# data.table[,-c(...)] behaves differently when defined in the package

Tags: r, data.table

UPD. Thanks to @RYoda, I found that I forgot to include `import(data.table)` in my `NAMESPACE` file. However, I still don't understand why all other `data.table` function calls worked correctly even without this `import()`, will be grateful if someone can explain it.

In my package, I define a function that, among other, excludes some columns from a data.table. I can define it in different ways:

```
# code in the package: \testexcl\R\test_exclude.R

test_exclude_col1 <- function(inpDT,col2excl){
  output <- inpDT[, -c(col2excl), with=F]
  invisible(output)
}

test_exclude_col2 <- function(inpDT,col2excl){
  output <- inpDT[, setdiff(names(inpDT), col2excl), with=F]
  invisible(output;
}
```

I then can use the function like this:

```
require(data.table)
require(testexcl) # my package
dt.iris <- data.table(iris)
dt.1 <- test_exclude_col1(dt.iris, 'Species') # Error
dt.2 <- test_exclude_col2(dt.iris, 'Species') # OK
```

`test_exclude_col2()` works as expected while `test_exclude_col1()` raises an error `Error in -c(col2excl) : invalid argument to unary operator`. What puzzles me the most is that if I define exactly the same code of `test_exclude_col1()` not in the package but in my session, it works correctly. Why does this happen?

I am on R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06), Win10 x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64, data.table_1.10.4, tools_3.3.3

P.S. To be sure that I'm working with the data.table, I've added this piece to the package:

```
test_exclude_col1a <- function(inpDT,col2excl){
  print(class(inpDT));
  inpDT <- data.table(inpDT);
  output <- inpDT[, -c(col2excl), with=F]
  invisible(output);
}
```

When I call `test_exclude_col1a(dt.iris, 'Species')`, it prints `[1] "data.table" "data.frame"` then gives the same error.

Comment: `test_exclude_col1` Works fine for me ? what is your data.table version?

Comment: I get this error only if I pass a `data.frame` (instead of `data.table`), e. g. `dt.3 <- test_exclude_col1(as.data.frame(iris), 'Species')` so I guess you are converting somewhere. Does your minimum example posted above produce the error on your machine?

Comment: sorry, I don't know what is the proper way to share a package, so far I just put it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zu4wv3bgu7wxzb/MRE.ZIP?dl=1

Comment: Your package `DESCRIPTION` file does not reference `data.table` and there is no `NAMESPACE` file to import the required data.table functions... Without that it is difficult to predict the behavior.

Comment: you're right, I only needed to add `import(data.table)` to the 'NAMESPACE' file (even no need to add `Imports:` section in the `DESCRIPTION` if I call `require(data.table)` before) - and it solved the problem. But I still don't understand why all other `data.table` function calls worked correctly and only this one raised an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `data.table` function in your package you have to

1. declare the package dependency so that the `data.table` package is installed if it 
   does not yet exist (e. g. via `Imports:` in the `DESCRIPTION` file) and
2. import the required functions into your package (using the `import()` function in the `NAMESPACE` file => `import(data.table)`

For more background see:

- http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html
- http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html